# Add task to task sheduler with python

Tags: python, automation

I'm looking for a script that adds a task to the windows task sheduler to automatically open "C:/program.exe" on login.

This is example code of what I'm expecting:

```
from winsheduler import *

shedule('C:/file.exe', on_login)
```

Any suggerstions?

Answer (score 0):

One approach i have used in the past is to create the task manually in the task scheduler, then use the following code to call the existing task.

You may find this [code](https://gist.github.com/nmpowell/dc8e7187948788c5c126f01755252164) useful. Ofcourse modify to suit your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but thing is that i'm looking for a fully automatic method as it's meant to be sent to my non techy friends.